# Where is the benefit in SQI parallel interface over SPI? Parallel vs. serial

Tags: avr, spi, parallel, serial-bus

Microchip is offering a number of serial SRAM chips with a communication protocol called SQI which is similar to SPI but with 4 parallel bits written at each CLK toggle.

If you can spend the extra 3 pins this makes sense. You can achieve a throughput of 4 times the rate of SPI.

However there is a catch - SPI is supported by all modern MCUs as a hardware module so it runs automatically and very quickly and CLK rates of several MHz are not a problem.

SQI is not supported by hardware so you have to bit bang the protocol. If my MCU, for example, runs on an 8MHz system clock and it is executing most instructions in a single cycle (AVR) I can expect SQI CLK rate of under 1MHz. This is based upon software SPI implementation which is also sub 1MHz and has slightly less code in it.

So let's say I can transfer 4 bits at a time, using SQI, with 800 KHz CLK (real world numbers), that is 3.2 Mbits per second.
However I can run SPI at 5MHz and get 5Mbits of data with less code and without having to wait with my application code while data is being sent or received over the communication lines.

So what is the point here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SQI is not supported by hardware...

Your premise, while correct for your particular MCU, is flawed in the general case. The MCUs that you have been looking at may not have SQI (which I believe is the same as Quad SPI or QSPI), there are many devices with hardware support for QSPI. (Note that "QSPI" is a confusing acronym because it is sometimes also used for "Queued SPI", which is different.)

For example: Many ARM MCUs (for example, [STM32](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/b0/7e/46/a8/5e/c1/48/01/DM00227538/files/DM00227538.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00227538.pdf) and [Atmel SAM](http://www.atmel.com/Images/44043_SAMA5D2-Quad-SPI-(QSPI)-Performance-ApplicationNote.pdf)) have a hardware peripheral that can do x1, x2, or x4 SPI and some execute from QSPI storage in addition to using such peripherals for data storage.

Most FPGAs support configuration over master serial (SPI) in x1, x2, or x4 widths. Some can even use dual QSPI flash chips for a full eight bits per clock. See the [Xilinx 7 series configuration UG](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug470_7Series_Config.pdf), ctrl-F "quad".

In these applications, the QSPI is not bit-bung, and is therefore four times faster. For your specific microcontroller (and many small 8-bit MCUs), you are correct and you will be better off with a regular x1 SPI flash. With many many microcontrollers, applications processors, and FPGAs, there is hardware support for x4 SPI and it is far faster.

Comment: Technically "Quad SPI" and "SQI" are two different things, the difference being the number of lines used for the command protocol.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for clarifying, I'm not completely familiar with "SQI". However, I believe my answer is still sufficient, yes?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with SQI either until I actually looked it up (I had written an answer earlier but deleted it), but yes, the rest of the answer applies for the most part. SQI support is simply rarer yet than Quad SPI support.

Comment: After some research, it seems that SQI(tm) from Microchip isn't actually an x4 protocol, and it seems that OP is referring to Quad SPI. From an SSI/Microchip doc, SQI is {CE#, SCK, SI, SO, WP#, HOLD#} which is essentially x1 SPI with a two extra control lines.

Comment: Right, but the communications itself happens over DIO0-3 rather than just SI.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I'm blind and apparently was looking at the wrong datasheet (for an x1 part). Thanks for the clarification.